# How to add an attribute to a link created inside a Post in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

From a Post or Page inside Wordpress, you can add a link from the WYSIWYG toolbar, you know by clicking the chain icon.

I would like to automatically add a data attribute to the link that is rendered by doing this. I can't seem to find where in WordPress this link gets created.

This would need to be a function in the theme's directory, correct?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I started hunting this one:  Searched wp core for "Or link to existing content", which shows up here:

/wp-includes/class-wp-editor.php  -  line 808:  public static function wp_link_dialog()

Also found some stuff here:

/wp-admin/includes/ajax-actions.php  -  search for "_ajax_linking_nonce"

---

It seems like there's an ajax request to get the list of linkable posts/pages, and then **javascript** handles the rest.

Good luck ;)

Comment: You might be better off adding a new button to the WYSIWYG tinyMCE editor.  This isn't particularly easy though, google it.

Comment: Or, if the data is easy, just type it in after you add the link =P